# Anonymous submission on arXiv

Tags: arxiv

I have to submit a paper in `NIPS 2017` which is an extension of a paper submitted to `ICDAR 2017`. As this paper is still under review, I want to put on arXiv using an anonymous submission for double blind review for NIPS. Here are my questions.

1. Can I submit an anonymous submission on arXiv
2. If yes, can I refer to the paper on arXiv

Comment: Pretty simple. NO.

Comment: so, I have to describe the base approach once more? @ShakeBaby

Comment: It seems that you have to. I understood your question as stated in my answer below. If this answer does not answer your question, I'd suggest that you edit and clarify your question. @cpwah

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understand your question. @FuzzyLeapfrog

Comment: There's a third option: 3) submit non-anonymously on arXiv. This assumes NIPS 2017 accepts publication of pre-prints, which is true of many venues (otherwise arXiv wouldn't exist).

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question, but [OpenReview does accept anonymous preprints](https://openreview.net/group?id=OpenReview.net%2FAnonymous_Preprint)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I submit an anonymous submission on arXiv

No, you can't submit to arXiv anonymously.

See https://arxiv.org/help/submit and https://arxiv.org/help/registerhelp where they say:

> It is a violation of our policies to misrepresent your identity or institutional affiliation.

Comment: That policy concerns registration. It doesn't say anything about anonymous submissions? In practice it would be partly impossible, as the submission history of an article shows the name of the registered member who submitted.