# Is there a "blind" e-print service?

Tags: peer-review, arxiv, preprint

Motivated by questions such as [Double blind review allowing arXiv submissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/double-blind-review-allowing-arxiv-submissions) :

is there a respectable e-print website (ideally Arxiv itself) that allows me to submit a "blind preprint", i.e., post a preprint without revealing its authors publicly? This would allow authors to have a preprint published, without breaking double-blind for journal submissions.

Ideally, the website would then include a way to contact the authors anonymously to discuss the paper.

Comment: [Anonymous submission on arXiv](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/88928/17254) mentions [OpenReview](https://openreview.net/), which is designed to host anonymous preprints for double-blind peer review, apparently primarily in computer science. I am not able to judge whether the relevant community finds it respectable.

Comment: Thanks @Anyon , both links are useful! Could you submit this as an answer?

Comment: @Anyon Does OpenReview accept preprints from individuals? It seems to be a system to (openly) manage the hosting and review of conferences and workshops to me.

Comment: @GoodDeeds It is unclear to me whether it accepts preprints unless submitted to one of the publication venues using OpenReview and I don't feel compelled to make an account to try it out.